# Why loop is only running 4 times?

Tags: javascript

The code below runs fine. No Problem

```
const isPalindrome = word => {

    const stk = [];
    let rword = "";
    
    for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        stk.push(word[i]);
    }
    console.log(stk)
    console.log(stk.length)
    for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        rword += stk.pop();
    console.log(rword)
    }
   
    return word === rword;
}


console.log(isPalindrome("racecar"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Oqy.png)

But When I run this code with stk.length, it runs only 4 times in the loop. Why such behaviour?

```
const isPalindrome = (word) => {
  const stk = [];
  let rword = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    stk.push(word[i]);
  }
  console.log(stk);
  console.log(stk.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < stk.length; i++) {
    rword += stk.pop();
    console.log(rword);
  }

  return word === rword;
};

console.log(isPalindrome("racecar"));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKGzw.png)

I expected that both code must give me the same results.

Comment: `stk` gets shorter with every `pop`…

Answer (score 2):

It's because [`Array#pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) mutates the array so if you iterate over `stk` and call `.pop()` on it, you reduce its actual length.

From MDN:

> The `pop()` method is a mutating method. It changes the length and the content of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Cause when u loop stk array, u pop an element from stk => stk's length decrease.

So after looped 4 times the stk's length becomes 4 and i increasing to 4 too, and the condition i<stk.length no longer match

so the loop break after 4 times

That's why the 1st example using word's length instead of stk